# spring integration dynamic header

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-integration-http

In Spring-integration Http request based on user logged in want to add dynamic header param.say for example if "A" user logged in & hitHttp request,now need to add dynamic 1 additional header,for others user,it should even the key too(i.e value as null)

For A user

```
<int:gateway id="requestGateway" service-interface="net.group.gateway.Gateway"  default-request-channel="jsonTransformationChannel">
            <int:default-header name="X-MW-LOGGEDID" expression="@requestData.getLoggedID()" />
            <int:default-header name="X-Srcvalue" value="56789" />
            <int:default-header name="content-type" value="application/json" />
            <int:default-header name="Accept" value="application/json" />
</int:gateway>
```

**For Other user**

```
<int:gateway id="requestGateway" service-interface="net.group.gateway.Gateway"  default-request-channel="jsonTransformationChannel">
            <int:default-header name="X-MW-LOGGEDID" expression="@requestData.getLoggedID()" />
            <int:default-header name="content-type" value="application/json" />
            <int:default-header name="Accept" value="application/json" />
 </int:gateway>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the story is really about that `X-Srcvalue`. And since you say it's OK to `null` for anyone else, that would better to use an `expression` instead of value.

```
<int:default-header name="X-Srcvalue" expression="USER == A ? 56789 : null" />
```

In the expression you can use any bean in the application context to perform the logic any complexity.

Comment: my problem,if other user logged in,under header the key itself "X-Srcvalue" should not present.for A user is not a prblm.

Comment: Well, the point is if value of that header to map is `null` it isn't going to be presented in the output message. See `MessageHeaderAccessor.setHeader()` implementation